# What is the right wait to get current URL?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What the right wait to get current `url` in react?

`window.location.pathname` or `props.match.path`

With `props.match` we got to pass the props to children to use it in the children. with Window.location we can access everywhere. What the point of using `props.match.path` anyway?

Comment: look 
if you are using react-router-dom in your app it should be used props .match.path if a used the if you are not used it should be used the window.location.pathname

Answer (score 0):

I assume you asking about `react-router`.

On the given path you want to emit some logic, for example rendering a component:

```
return (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path={"/500"} component={Page500} />
      ...
    </Switch>
  </div>
);
```

While using the `pathname` you will write the same logic in every component, which is more fragile to bugs, like changing the pathname:

```
if (location.pathname === "/500") {
  return <Page500 />
}
```

Moreover, you lose the benefits of [`match` property](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/match.md).

Answer (score -1):

look 
if you are using react-router-dom in your app it should be used props .match.path if a used the if you are not used it should be used the window.location.pathname